# Can I keep home-made salad dressing un-refrigerated?

Tags: food-safety, salad-dressing

My salad dressing has extra virgin olive oil (EVOO), raspberry wine vinegar, chives, sugar, salt & pepper, lemon juice and lemon zest. Can I keep it un-refrigerated for 18 hours?

Comment: Who downvoted - this is not a stupid question I'd say. Needs more quantities to determine whether it qualifies as a vinegar pickle or just a random mixture of stuff :)

Comment: Can you provide your recipe?

Answer (score 0):

Me think you should be OK.

The dressing does not contain garlic which can be an issue in regards of botulism.

I don't know if chive has the same botulism problem as garlic, you might check that out